# Pageres (using PhantomJS) selector is not working?

Tags: phantomjs, screenshot

I'm trying to use the example (`pageres yeoman.io 1366x768 --selector '.page-header'`) on the [documentation page](https://github.com/sindresorhus/pageres) and all I get is the FULL page screenshot. Neither the --selector or --hide attributes work for me?

What am I doing wrong?

Ta,

Ian.

Comment: What platform are you on? Win/Tux/OSX/other? What version of pageres & PhantomJS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

On windows you have to use other quotation marks. Only `"` can be used to pass continous parameters to programs. So `'`, `` ` `` and `´` cannot be used. Since the parsing breaks the selector, it cannot be found on the page and pageres defaults to a complete page screenshot.